# Can I put google ads on site that gets 90% organic traffic from bing

Tags: google-adsense, search-results, traffic, bing, google-adsense-policies

I have a site that gets 20 to 30 visitors (sometimes 50+) daily from organic search. Organic search traffics mostly comes from **Bing** search engine, not Google.

I have read that before, Google Adsense performs well for organic search traffics instead of social media traffics. I want to know that, Is Google adsense performs well for **Google organic search traffics** only? or Bing, Yahoo, Baidu and other organic search traffics also good to put Google ads on site that receives more organic visitors other than Google search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Google Ads for any site ignoring the organic traffic it receives from any Search Engine.

Comment: Also, can you let me know how is this happening, as in, how are you getting 90% of the traffic from Bing, is your website related to some niche domain which is somehow related with Bing users?